# Vertical aligning single line items in a double line navigation menu

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm currently building a Wordpress website whose navigation menu has items with long titles requiring a second line. However, some of the remaining items are only short words, and don't need to wrap onto a second line.

I would like to make the single line items to vertically align in the middle of the menu, but at the moment they seem to stay at the top. I have tried the vertical-align: middle css, but that didn't solve the problem.

This is the main list css:

```
    .main-navigation li {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 116.5px;
    word-wrap: normal;
    background-color: #fec20f;
    }
```

Turning off the height works, but loses the background colour above and below the item.

I have made a jsfiddle to show what I currently have:
http://jsfiddle.net/KM99G/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `.main-navigation li a` a `display: table-cell;` instead of `display: inline-block;`.
And set `vertical-align: middle;` on the `a`, not on the `li`

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/KM99G/4/

Comment: Thanks, but the item in the second cell is now stuck against the left of the menu, and the borders are missing. Any advice?

Comment: Thanks, but I still have the problem with the second cell aligning the text to the left.

Comment: I updated your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KM99G/9/ It works the way you want now. I made to much changes to explain here, hope you see it yourself.

Comment: Thanks very much. Will copy it across.

Comment: the whole area is not clickable

Answer (score -1):

LIke this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KM99G/3/)**

**css**

```
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu {
    display: inline-block !important;
text-align: left;
width: 100%;
}

.main-navigation li {
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size: 18px;
height: 50px;
padding-top: 0px;
text-align: center;
width: 116.5px;
word-wrap: normal;
background-color: #fec20f;
    display:table-cell;
}


.main-navigation .current-menu-item > a, .main-navigation .current-menu-ancestor > a, .main-navigation .current_page_item > a, .main-navigation .current_page_ancestor > a {
color: #fec20f;
background-color: #000000;
font-weight: bold;
height: 50px;
width: 116.5px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.main-navigation li a, .main-navigation li {
display: table-cell;
text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
list-style: none;
}

nav {
display: block;
}

.main-navigation li a {
color: #000000;
}

.main-navigation li a, .main-navigation li {
display: table-cell;
text-decoration: none;
}

.main-navigation li {
font-size: 18px;
text-align: center;
}

.main-navigation li {
line-height: 1.42857143;
}

body {
    width: 960px;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the item in the second cell is now stuck against the left of the menu, and the borders are missing. Any advice?